# Subscribe to get messages not working in Robot framework MQTT Library

Tags: robotframework, mqtt, mosquitto

I am new to Robot framework and MQTT. I have brought up a subscriber/publisher setup using mosquitto. I have written a code to publish to a subscribed topic. The code for Publish is working fine and I am able to see the output in the subscriber window. However, the subscribe keyword is not working for me.

I have tried both Subscribe and subscribe and validate. For the former, I am getting Messages=[], and for the latter 'The expected payload didn't arrive in the topic'. The screenshot of the codes are attached.

```
Subscribe and get messages
    Subscribe   MQTTtest2   qos=2   timeout=1   limit=0
    I Publish an MQTT request
    ${messages}=    Subscribe   MQTTtest2   qos=2   timeout=5   limit=0
    log to console  Messages=${messages}

I Publish an MQTT request
    connect   127.0.0.1
    publish  MQTTtest2   testmessage  2  ${false}
    disconnect

MQTT_SUBSCRIBE_AND_VALIDATE
[Tags]  mqtt
[Setup]     Connect     127.0.0.1
I SUBSCRIBE to a Topic
[Teardown]  Disconnect

I SUBSCRIBE to a Topic
#connect  ${MQTT.hostname}
subscribe and validate  ${MQTT.topic}  ${MQTT.qos}  ${MQTT.message}  5
#disconnect
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? [Subscribe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BChTu.png)
[Publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Eqa.png)

Comment: Can you please add the code as a code block in text. Screenshots shouldn't be used for this. This can be achieved through the [edit] functionality of your question.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code block. In it, the publish is working fine as can be seen from the Publish Screenshot

Comment: If I'm correct you're using the MQTTLibrary ([GitHub](https://github.com/randomsync/robotframework-mqttlibrary)) and there are several example files in the source [test folder](https://github.com/randomsync/robotframework-mqttlibrary/tree/master/tests) that might be interesting to look at.

Comment: I had also tried the exact codes in test folder. Same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect to the broker in case of subscribe operation too with the `Connect` keyword.

Currently you have not established connection before any of the `Subscribe` keywords. In your `I Publish an MQTT request` you do a connect so that succeeds, but then you do a disconnect as well so the next subscribe fails again.

If you modify your test like this:

```python
*** Keywords ***
Subscribe And Get Messages
    Subscribe   topic=MQTTtest2   qos=2   timeout=5   limit=0
    I Publish An MQTT Request
    ${messages}=    Subscribe   topic=MQTTtest2   qos=2   timeout=5   limit=0
    Log To Console  Messages=${messages}

I Publish An MQTT Request
    Publish  topic=MQTTtest2   testmessage  2  ${false}

*** Test Cases ***
MQTT test
    [Tags]  mqtt
    [Setup]     Connect     127.0.0.1
    Subscribe And Get Messages
    [Teardown]  Disconnect
```

It should work correctly:

```
==============================================================================
Robot Framework.My Test
==============================================================================
MQTT test                                                             .Messages=[b'testmessage']
MQTT test                                                             | PASS |
```

Also it seems the MQTT library registers as a new client with each `Connect` so if you do separate connect/disconnect for each subscribe and publish, that probably won't work for you as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think 'Also it seems the MQTT library registers as a new client with each Connect so if you do separate connect/disconnect for each subscribe and publish, that probably won't work for you as you would expect.' was the problem. I got subscribe and get message working, but subscribe and validate is still not working. Can you help out? I will attach the code i used

Comment: The error i am receieving is 'The expected payload didn't arrive in the topic'

Comment: @aswathy I have checked this  `Subscribe and validate` keyword but does not work for me either. Based on that with a simple `Subscribe` I receive the correct payload and with this keyword I do not, it might be a library bug. You can try to open an issue or ask help on GitHUb. https://github.com/randomsync/robotframework-mqttlibrary/issues

Comment: Thank you Bence! I had raised the bug on Dec 5th..I haven't received any updates yet

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe and Validate seems to be working now.

```
    *** Variable ***
${mqtt-server}   127.0.0.1
${mqtt-path}    ABCD
${message-payload}  MQTT-Test-2.robot payload1 test message from RobotFramework
${message-payload2}  MQTT-Test-2.robot payload2 test message from RobotFramework

*** Keywords ***
Subscribe And Get Messages
    Subscribe   topic=${mqtt-path}  qos=2   timeout=5   limit=0
    #I Publish An MQTT Request
    Publish     topic=${mqtt-path}    message=${message-payload}
    ${messages}=    Subscribe    topic=${mqtt-path}   qos=1   timeout=5   limit=0
    Log To Console  Messages=${messages}

Subscribe And Validate Messages
    Subscribe   topic=${mqtt-path}  qos=2   timeout=5   limit=0
    #I Publish An MQTT Request
    Publish     topic=${mqtt-path}    message=${message-payload2}    
    ${messages}=    Subscribe And Validate    topic=${mqtt-path}   qos=1   timeout=5    payload=${message-payload2}
    Log To Console  Messages=${messages}    

Publish An MQTT Request
    Publish     topic=${mqtt-path}    message=${message-payload}

*** Test Cases ***
MQTT test
    [Tags]  mqtt
    [Setup]  Connect    127.0.0.1
    Publish An MQTT Request
    Subscribe And Get Messages
    Subscribe And Validate Messages
    [Teardown]  Disconnect
```

==============================================================================

## MQTT-Test-3 :: This is a MQTT test project: MQTT-Test-2.robot that explores...

MQTT test                                                             ..Messages=['MQTT-Test-2.robot payload1 test message from RobotFramework']
.Messages=None

### MQTT test                                                             | PASS |

MQTT-Test-3 :: This is a MQTT test project: MQTT-Test-2.robot that... | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed

## 1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and provide more details.